# Java Docker Container, how to check the output?

Tags: java, docker, gitlab, gitlab-ci

We have a GitLab Pipeline with the following job which runs inside a Docker Container that has Java installed:

```
generate_openapi_server_code:
  image: java:17
  stage: validate
  tags:
    - test
  script:
    - "wget https://<artifactory-host-url>/artifactory/Maven-Central-remote-cache/org/openapitools/openapi-generator-cli/6.3.0/openapi-generator-cli-6.3.0.jar -O openapi-generator-cli.jar"
    - "java -jar openapi-generator-cli.jar generate -g spring -o out -i dispo.yaml | sed '/WARN/q1'"
```

As you can see in the first step it downloads the Java Lib from our Maven Repo and then starts the program. In order we can validate the outcome of the program we try to check the console output with the `sed` command tool. The problem is that `sed` is not available in that image so the job fails with: `sed: missing command`.

Do you have an idea how to check the Java's output in a container? Do you know a better container which has all tools at hand, i.e. Java 17 and sed?

Comment: Have you considered just installing `sed` in your job?

Comment: Create a Docker image from the target image you are currently using and install sed i.e. 
FROM <target image>
RUN apt-get install -y sed

Answer (score 1):

Strange, I just checked the `amazoncorretto:17` locally and it seems to have the `sed` command. You can, however, build your own docker image which is based on `amazoncorretto:17` (or any image for that matter) and install sed (even though when I checked locally it is already present). You can also use `"java -jar openapi-generator-cli.jar generate -g spring -o out -i dispo.yaml | grep -q 'WARN' && exit 1"` which should do the same. (I would assume `grep` is already present)

Comment: I used `amazoncorretto` only as an example, actually we used in our company another image called `java:17`. `amazoncorretto` failed in my job right away with the first command `wget` in my script. So I didn't notice that at least `sed` was there available.

Comment: The problem with `grep` is that exit code cannot regard the whole output, instead it will always regard the last pipe as the final result so when in the last output there is no WARN but there was one some rows before the exit code relates to the last output. So `grep` has the option `-z` to regard the whole output as one line. However, the `grep` version in my image does not support the `-z` option.

Answer (score 0):

In the end the image had at least the `awk` program installed and so I could check Java's output by `awk`'s help for a special character sequence and if there were matches then exit the program right away with exit code 1:

```
java -jar openapi-generator-cli.jar generate -g spring -o out -i dispo.yaml | awk '{ print; } $0 ~ "WARN" { exit 1; }'
```